# Facebook wont sign in on one specific account

Tags: ios, facebook

We have recently implemented the Facebook SDK. For all our team and testers they can sign in with no issues; but for one team member it always gives a 'user canceled the login error' - it doesn't help that I'm on west coast and he is on the east coast so I can't debug it - however I do have the following print out of the error via TestFlight...

> 2013-06-27 20:33:27 facebookFirstTimeLogInUserCanceled error:Error
>   Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>
> (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x1e5d3790
>
> {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts
>   Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request:
>   Service temporarily unavailable" UserInfo=0x1f0761c0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this
>   access request: Service temporarily unavailable},
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=,
>   expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate:
>   0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
>
> 2013-06-27 20:33:35 Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"
>
> UserInfo=0x1e5c2190  {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={ body =
>   { error = { code = 2500; message = "An active access token must be
>   used to query information about the current user."; type =
>   OAuthException; }; }; code = 400; },
>   com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400} 2013-06-27 20:33:35 Unexpected
>   error:Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1e5c2190
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={ body = { error = { code =
>   2500; message = "An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user."; type = OAuthException; }; };
>   code = 400; }, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
>
> 2013-06-27 20:33:44 TestFlight: End of Session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have had the exact some problem: Everybody was able to sign in – except for one user, who got the following error message when he wanted to log in via Facebook's Login dialog built into iOS 6:

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)`
`FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled`

When we couldn't figure out why the system login was cancelled (`SystemLoginCancelled`) and `The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request`, we decided to pass on iOS 6 native authentication and use fast-app-switching instead.
Bypassing iOS 6 native authentication can be done by using `FBSession`'s (unfortunately deprecated) class method

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions
                            allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                       completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
```

This method calls

```
+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithPermissions:(NSArray*)permissions
                            allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
                      allowSystemAccount:(BOOL)allowSystemAccount
                                  isRead:(BOOL)isRead
                         defaultAudience:(FBSessionDefaultAudience)defaultAudience
                       completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler;
```

with the third parameter (`allowSystemAccount`) set to `NO`, which causes the app to fall back on fast-app-switching.

When the user then tried to log in again, the following message appeared:

[image]

It turned out that the user had turned off platform applications, which prevented our app from integrating Facebook. After platform applications had been turned back on, the login was finally working.

In Facebook you can turn on platform applications by going to your `Privacy Settings` and selecting `Apps` from the main menu. Now you can click on `Edit` to reveal a button that says `Turn On Platform`.

Comment: Thanks! - let me check to see if this is the case for us too. I've been refactoring a lot of my facebook code and found I was getting better error reporting by looking at error.fberrorShouldNotifyUser and error.fberrorUserMessage etc - did you look at that error message and was it helpful?

Comment: Yes, we examined `fberrorShouldNotifyUser` and `fberrorUserMessage`, but the results were totally useless: Facebook told us to not notify the user (`fberrorShouldNotifyUser` was `NO`) and therefore provided no user message (`fberrorUserMessage` was `nil`).

Comment: We confirmed that this was the issue! The `userInfo` gave more information - but for now I have a generic error and list this as a possibility. `UserInfo= {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginDisallowedWithoutError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1fd9bbe0, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 487953444610527, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy: 0x20878d20>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}`

Comment: Great answer! I was getting a slightly different error (Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Service temporarily unavailable" ) but the issue was the same: no applications were enabled in the user Applications setup page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw that com.facebook.sdk error 2 message in an app I was working on, and it turned out for me, the problem was that the user had denied facebook access to our app without realizing it. Have your user go into Settings -> Facebook and see if your app is in the list and make sure the switch is turned to ON.

Comment: Thanks SeanT - I had him do that on a previous build and it wasn't showing that app listed in the facebook settings. I'm going to ask him to check again as I didn't have the logging enabled before and to be double sure.

Comment: Another possible cause for issues with the iOS6 integration (may not be the issue here) is if the user changed their FB password but still have the old password in their iphone's settings

Comment: SeanT - We double checked - this isn't the issue - the app isn't showing at all in his Facebook settings page.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, that was my only idea.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the case with the platform thing or the user might have not accepted the invitation. While login via the Facebook app and the browser works this one doesn't. He has to go to https://developers.facebook.com, go to apps and accept the invitation.